# How do you implement Javascript onfocus() and onblur() for a password field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

According to my title  how to implement the `onfocus` and `onblur` to the password field? Default value is password (readable) and when we click the password field it will return to password format.

Here an example, I don't want to see "●●●●●●●●" but "Password" instead

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="password" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='password') ? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='') ? 'password' : this.value;" />
```

**Update**

Google result I found [**Change Input Type Dynamically**](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/change-input-type-dynamically/) but the code is too long. Maybe jquery can make it shorter.

Comment: What you have works: http://jsfiddle.net/2M9Az/ What do you want to do differently?, or possibly, which browser is giving you trouble?

Comment: Actually it working, but here I want to display Password (readable), before we click to the field and not ********

Comment: Ah, but you do want it masked after it's typed in?

Comment: so what you really want is a text input, that when it doesn't have the focus is contains the word "Password" but when it does have focus, you want it to show the email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have trouble in Internet Explorer if you try and use 1 field because IE will **not** let you change the `type` of field.

You'll need to use 2 fields, and when the text input is focused, hide it, show the password input, and focus it.

You'd need something like this (using jQuery):

```
<input type="text" id="fakeemail" value="email@domain.com"/>
<input type="password" id="realemail" value="" name="email" style="display:none;"/>

$('#fakeemail').focus(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#realemail').show().focus();
});
$('#realemail').blur(function(){
  if(this.value == ''){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#fakeemail').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Check the input's value in blur and it's a great answer: `$('#realemail').blur(function(){  if(this.value == "") {  $(this).hide();  $('#fakeemail').show();}});`

Comment: hmmm.. I don't see how it work. http://jsfiddle.net/nzyrx/ I just update my question.

Answer (score 1):

change the `type` attr. dynamically:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="email@domain.com" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='email@domain.com') ? '' : this.value;this.type='password';" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='') ? 'email@domain.com' : this.value;this.type='text';" />
```

(I suggest you do this with a script instead of inline).

Comment: You can't do this cross-browser, in IE specifically.

Comment: it will returned to `type="text"`

Comment: @Nick: that is interesting. Side-effect of only testing it on Chrome. My only other suggestion is to maybe create a `text` *and* `password` element, and juggle them :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try using some jQuery and moving field labels around with CSS positioning. Check this guy's implementation out: http://graphicpush.com/more-accessible-input-pre-filled-text-with-jquery

The site that he links to also has a nice fade effect on the input fields on focus (but his implementation is a bit nicer than the one he links to).

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't - the type of the field isn't important because it's being masked by its associated label (which will be 'password' as readable text). This is a good approach because people who don't have javascript turned on still get the field hinting, so it's accessible too, as well as being more semantically correct than using a dummy input field, for eg.

Comment: @holisk but he wants the user to be able to read the actual password, not just the label "Password".

Comment: But how can the user read their password before they've entered anything into the box? That's a level of magic that I don't think even jQuery can manage :/